# JQuery loading after my script inside Twig template

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, webpack-encore

I have some Javascript code inside a Twig template that uses jQuery. The script seems to be loading before jQuery, so it throws a `$ is not defined` error. I can't figure out why it's loading before the main bundle that includes jQuery (compiled with `webpack-encore`).

JQuery does load because I can reference it from the console or wrap the script inside a `setTimeout` to force it to be loaded later.

I have this base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            {% block title %}Welcome!
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

The page template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
/// ...
<script>
$.change(/*...*/); // $ is not defined
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .enableSassLoader()
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    .autoProvidejQuery()
;
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

`app.js`:

```
require('./styles/app.scss');
import $ from 'jquery';
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

This was the generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">
    <script src="/build/runtime.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/build/app.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main class="col p-4 content flex-grow-1">
        <!-- page content -->
        <script>
            // $ is not defined here
        </script>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So your issue is that probably you are calling the app.js compiled file after your `<script>..` so what I recommend is putting your javascript logic inside the app.js

Comment: The first thing to verify the order of loading is saving source code from the browser directly into the static file and checking if it's valid. If it isn't you just should modify it in the satic file and then reflect in your PHP project. We cannot debug your problem when you show us some lines from your templates in random order.

Comment: @biesior there is nothing random about what is posted. They have shown everything pertinent to the situation. The Symfony, twig, and webpack-encore tags are key here.

Comment: @biesior You're right, I forgot to include the generated HTML. I've updated the question and added an answer. The problem was that Symphony was inserting the scripts with the `defer` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found in these lines from the generated HTML:

```
<script src="/build/runtime.js" defer></script>
<script src="/build/app.js" defer></script>
```

The `defer` attribute forces the Javascript files where jQuery is defined, to be loaded after the page is rendered. Since I'm adding inline Javascript in the page, it's loaded *before* `app.js`.

Since there is no way to add deferred inline Javascript in HTML, there are two alternatives:

- Set the following configuration in `config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml`:

```yaml
script_attributes:
    defer: false
```

This disables the behavior described. This solution is not ideal because using `defer` is desirable in my case.

- Define Javascript code outside of the template (import it with `encore_entry_script_tags`).

Save your Javascript file in `assets/` and, if you have a similar base template as the one in the question, import it in your page template like this:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('your_file') }}
{% endblock %}
```

In `webpack.config.js`:

```js
Encore
//...
.addEntry('your_file','./assets/your_file.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: You must note that you can’t use require and import at the same
> time in your node program and it is more preferred to use require
> instead of import as you are required to use the experimental module
> flag feature to run import program.
>
> --https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-node-js-require-and-es6-import-and-export/

The article above also mentions that with `require` "you can directly run the code" in this case the code is defining the `$` function, so you want to run that.

My projects are as follows with no problems:

app.js:

```
require('./styles/app.scss');
const $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;
```

Comment the following line in webpack.config.js:

```
//.autoProvidejQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem ended up being that Symfony was including the `app.js` file with the `defer` attribute so even though it appeared **before** my inline javascript, it was still being loaded afterwards.